# Two step method or two steps method

Tags: orthography

It seems like a particular dance is called "Two-step". It gave me some doubts about how to spell step in the description of a method I use. If my method has two steps, should it be called a two step method or a two steps method?

Comment: It should be called a two-step method, IMO.

Comment: For two reasons, 'two-step' is the correct option. First, the word 'step' is here being used metaphorically – one might even say as a unit. Units rarely pluralise as premodifiers (a three-ton elephant / a six-mile hike). Second, attributive nouns are rarely used in plural form in any case (a sweet shop (not sweets shop) / a log cabin / an animal shelter).

Comment: In most cases, nouns modifying nouns should be singular. For instance, it's _Shoe Store_, with singular _Shoe_, even though people normally don't buy only one shoe there.

Answer (score 1):

[Edwin Ashworth](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/164723/two-step-method-or-two-steps-method#comment-343194) has already described the correctness better than I.

> For two reasons, 'two-step' is the correct option. First, the word 'step' is here being used metaphorically – one might even say as a unit. Units rarely pluralise as premodifiers (a three-ton elephant / a six-mile hike). Second, attributive nouns are rarely used in plural form in any case (a sweet shop (not sweets shop) / a log cabin / an animal shelter).

But I wanted to add, it's not uncommon for [methods](http://www.edutopia.org/blog/classroom-management-intervention-two-step-richard-curwin) or [things](http://www.ntrwa.org/texastwostepconference.aspx) to be called the "X Two-Step". So if your method is for squeezing a fruit to extract juice, you could call it the "Juice Two-Step". This  is essentially a [marketing technique](http://epikco.com/the-familiarity-principle/) playing peoples' familiarity with the [dance moves](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two-step).

Comment: As an aside, please don't accept this answer; Edwin deserves the credit, I just couldn't fit what I wanted to say into a comment.